# Linux: vc_dispmanx_display_open returns invalid handle

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, framebuffer, raspbian

I want to copy the framebuffer to an LCD display on my raspberry pi running raspbian. To do so I am using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "RAIO8870.h"
#include <bcm_host.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    DISPMANX_DISPLAY_HANDLE_T main_display_handle;
    DISPMANX_RESOURCE_HANDLE_T screen_resource_handle;

    VC_RECT_T rectangle;

    int ret;
    uint32_t image_prt;
    uint16_t image[ PICTURE_PIXELS ];


    bcm_host_init();

    if ( !bcm2835_init() )
    return ( -1 );

    TFT_init_board();       
    TFT_hard_reset();
    RAIO_init();

    RAIO_SetBacklightPWMValue( 255 );

    uint32_t screen=0;


    printf("Open display[%i]...\n", screen );
    // open main framebuffer device
    main_display_handle = vc_dispmanx_display_open( screen );
    if ( !main_display_handle )
    {
        printf("\n Unable to open  display %i Handle: %i",screen,main_display_handle);
        return( -1 );
    }
```

The program always exits in the if condition, as `vc_dispmanx_display_open` does return 0. I was not able to find any documentation about this function.
So why does it return an invalid handle and how to avoid this?

Comment: According to [this](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=26661&p=244817) `-1` is also a possible return value on error, which means your check is wrong. It needs to be e.g. `if (main_display_handle <= 0) { /* error */ }`

Comment: The handle returned is always 0. As 0 is never a valid handle for anything, it doesn't work, even with your check condition.